# Method not doing queries on Odoo v10 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

I have this wizard method:

```
@api.multi
def search_partner_seniat(self):
    """ Check vat of the partner and update iva rate
    """
    self.ensure_one()
    vat = self.vat.upper()
    res = {
        'name': _('The requested contributor does not exist'),
        'vat_subjected': False,
        'vat': vat,
        'wh_iva_agent': False,
        'wh_iva_rate': 0.0
    }

    if 'VE' in vat:
        vat = vat[2:]

    # assumption: both methods in new api style
    if self.env['res.partner'].check_vat_ve(vat): 
        update_vals = self.env['seniat.url']._dom_giver(vat) 
        if update_vals:   
            res.update(update_vals)   #self.write(res)

    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_model': 'search.info.partner.seniat',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'res_id': self.id,
        'views': [(False, 'form')],
        'target': 'new',
    }
```

This is a wizard that should check for a specific `vat` and show me the results of it, otherwise it shows this message `The requested contributor does not exist`

Howver, this is a migration I'm doing from v8 to v10 community.

So at this moment, it isn't returning anything, seems like it's not checking the table or something.

This method calls `check_vat_ve` and `_dom_giver` methods, which are like this:

```
@api.multi
def _dom_giver(self, vat): 
    """ Check and validates that the vat is a passport,
    id or rif, to send information to SENIAT and returns the
    partner info that provides.
    """
    name = ''
    url_seniat = ''

    url_obj = self.search([], limit=1) 
    if url_obj.name:
        name = url_obj.name

    if url_obj.url_seniat:
        url_seniat = url_obj.url_seniat
    url1 = name + '%s'
    url2 = url_seniat + '%s'
    vat = self._validate_rif(vat) 
    if vat:
        return self._get_rif(vat, url1, url2) 
    else:
        return False

@api.model
def check_vat_ve(self, vat): #, context=None
    """ Check Venezuelan VAT number, locally called RIF.
    RIF: JXXXXXXXXX RIF VENEZOLAN
         IDENTIFICATION CARD: VXXXXXXXXX
         FOREIGN IDENTIFICATION CARD: EXXXXXXXXX
    """

    #if context is None:
        #context = {}
    if re.search(r'^[VJEGP][0-9]{9}$', vat):
        return True
    if re.search(r'^([VE][0-9]{1,8}|[D][0-9]{9})$', vat):
        return True
    return False
```

All these methods originally looked like this:

```
def search_partner_seniat(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    """ Check vat of the partner and update iva rate
    """
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    this = self.browse(cr, uid, ids)[0]
    su_obj = self.pool.get('seniat.url')
    rp_obj = self.pool.get('res.partner')
    vat = this.vat.upper()
    res = {'name': _('The requested contributor does not exist'),
           'vat_subjected': False, 'vat': vat, 'wh_iva_agent': False,
           'wh_iva_rate': 0.0}

    if 'VE' in vat:
        vat = vat[2:]

    if rp_obj.check_vat_ve(vat, context=context):
        res = su_obj._dom_giver(cr, uid, vat, context)
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, res)

    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_model': 'search.info.partner.seniat',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'res_id': this.id,
        'views': [(False, 'form')],
        'target': 'new',
    }

def check_vat_ve(self, vat, context=None):
    """ Check Venezuelan VAT number, locally called RIF.
    RIF: JXXXXXXXXX RIF VENEZOLAN
         IDENTIFICATION CARD: VXXXXXXXXX
         FOREIGN IDENTIFICATION CARD: EXXXXXXXXX
    """

    if context is None:
        context = {}
    if re.search(r'^[VJEGP][0-9]{9}$', vat):
        return True
    if re.search(r'^([VE][0-9]{1,8}|[D][0-9]{9})$', vat):
        return True
    return False

def _dom_giver(self, cr, uid, vat, context=None):
    """ Check and validates that the vat is a passport,
    id or rif, to send information to SENIAT and returns the
    partner info that provides.
    """
    if context is None:
        context = {}

    url_obj = self.browse(cr, uid, self.search(cr, uid, []))[0]
    url1 = url_obj.name + '%s'
    url2 = url_obj.url_seniat + '%s'
    vat = self._validate_rif(cr, uid, vat, context=None)
    if vat:
        return self._get_rif(cr, uid, vat, url1, url2, context=context)
    else:
        return False
```

It is working as expected on Odoo v8 of course.

Any ideas?

I think it has something to do with these declarations on `_dom_giver`:

```
    name = ''
    url_seniat = ''
```

But I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your old version code you are writing wizard record.

**self.write(cr, uid, ids, res)**

In new version code write line is in comment.

**#self.write(res)**

In new version code vals are preparing but it is not use.

You should remove comment in write method &  check it.

This may help you.